# Unable to download a beta APK published on Google Play

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I've uploaded the first APK of my game on the Google Play Developer Console for beta testing. The publication went well, and the application is now available for my beta testers.

However, nobody is able to download the APK on his phone nor tablet. When clicking on the download link provided by the Google Play Developer Console, testers get the following errors:

- using Play Store: Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account
- using Google Chrome: This app is incompatible with all of your devices

I don't understand this error, as phones and tablets we're using appear in the compatible devices list given by the Google Play Developer Console for the APK file.

Please note that we are able to manually upload the same APK on phones and tablets; this works well.

Other precisions:

- The game is based on LibGDX
- I built the release APK with Eclipse (Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package...)
- Testers belong to a Google Group that has been configured for my application beta testing

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.XXX.XXX"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0-beta01" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.axlsofts.tolum.android.AndroidLauncher"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

I also had a look to [Android <uses-features> documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html), and it seems that permissions I use don't imply any feature that could make devices incompatible.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well You havn't mentioned anything about who is able to test. 
You might need to create a google group and add all your friends

[This](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) might help you a lot

I don't see anything wrong with your Android Manifest

If you encounter further problems, Check your code again

If you find no errors in your code, then there is a "Contact Us" button on the google support page that may be able to help you (It helped me)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, testers belong to a Google Group that I configured in the Google Play Developer Console to test my beta APK. I will follow your advice and send a message to the Google support. Thanks again.